# Modifying or Unwinding deep nested arrays with mongo query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

After having made my own aggregation pipeline, I have arrived at the following result:

```js
[
    {
      "_id": "53712c7238b8d900008ef71c",
      "address": [
        {
          "_id": "53712c7238b8d900008ef71b",
          "phoneNumber": "4092348294",
          ...
        }
      ],
      "name": "TestDealer",
      "vehicles": [
        {
          "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef720",
          "createdAt": "2014-05-12T20:08:00.000Z",
          "tags": [
            "vehicle"
          ],
          "opts": [
            {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71e",
              "hasSunroof": false,
              ...
            }
          ],
          "listed": true,
          "disclosures": [
            {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71f",
              "waterDamage": false,
              ...
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71d",
              "year": 2007,
              ...
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a17",
          "createdAt": "2014-05-14T19:17:00.000Z",
          "tags": [
            "vehicle"
          ],
          "opts": [
            {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a15",
              "hasSunroof": false,
              ....
              "other": []
            }
          ],
          "listed": true,
          "disclosures": [
            {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a16",
              "waterDamage": false,
              ...
            }
          ],
          "details": [
            {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a14",
              "year": 2013,
              ...
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, `vehicles` is an array of subdocuments (vehicles) that follow a specific schema:

- details: an array of `details` subdocs
- opts: an array of `opts` subdocs
- disclosures: an array of `disclosures` subdocs

For each of `details`, `disclosures` and `opts` I would like to return the first subdoc in the array as opposed to an array. However, I'm not sure where to start. I can't really $unwind vehicles because it is possible that it might be empty.

Here's is what my final data should look like:

```js
[
    {
      "_id": "53712c7238b8d900008ef71c",
      "address": [
        {
          "_id": "53712c7238b8d900008ef71b",
          "phoneNumber": "4092348294",
          ...
        }
      ],
      "name": "TestDealer",
      "vehicles": [
        {
          "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef720",
          "createdAt": "2014-05-12T20:08:00.000Z",
          "tags": [
            "vehicle"
          ],
          "opts": {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71e",
              "hasSunroof": false,
              ...
          },
          "listed": true,
          "disclosures": {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71f",
              "waterDamage": false,
              ...
          },
          "details": {
              "_id": "53712fa138b8d900008ef71d",
              "year": 2007,
              ...
          }
        },
        {
          "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a17",
          "createdAt": "2014-05-14T19:17:00.000Z",
          "tags": [
            "vehicle"
          ],
          "opts": {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a15",
              "hasSunroof": false,
              ....
              "other": []
          },
          "listed": true,
          "disclosures": {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a16",
              "waterDamage": false,
              ...
          },
          "details": {
              "_id": "5373c6439058859af7904a14",
              "year": 2013,
              ...
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the aggregation I do to get my data (in CoffeeScript):

```js
      {
        $match:
          _id: ObjectId(params.id)
      }
      {
        $unwind: '$inventories'
      }
      {
        $match:
          'inventories._id': 'active'
      }
      {
        $redact:
          $cond:
            if:
              $eq:['$listed',false]
            then: '$$PRUNE'
            else: '$$DESCEND'
      }
      {
        $project:
          address: 1
          name: '$dealerName'
          email: '$_id.email'
          vehicles: '$inventories.vehicles'
      }
```

As well as the original data:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "53712c7238b8d900008ef71c" ),
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "createdAt" : Date( 1399925280000 ),
  "password" : "$2a$10$3dhicJuONkXeI9mQflXF0.JftAx7mLQaY2./6a3O7xdrs5qfH2zMW",
  "firstName" : "TestName",
  "lastName" : "testName",
  "dealerName" : "TestDealer",
  "dealerType" : "Franchised Dealer",
  "emailIsVerified" : false,
  "lastLoggedInAt" : Date( 1400247300000 ),
  "expiresAt" : Date( 4524062882000 ),
  "deletedAt" : null,
  "updatedAt" : Date( 1400251500000 ),
  "inventories" : [ 
    { "title" : "activeInventory",
      "_id" : "active",
      "vehicles" : [ 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "53712fa138b8d900008ef720" ),
          "createdAt" : Date( 1399925280000 ),
          "tags" : [ 
            "vehicle" ],
          "opts" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53712fa138b8d900008ef71e" ),
              "hasSunroof" : false,
              "hasSnowTires" : false,
              "hasPowerWindows" : false,
              "hasNavigationSystem" : false,
              "hasManuals" : false,
              "hasMags" : false,
              "hasLeather" : false,
              "hasKeylessEntry" : false,
              "hasHeatedSeats" : false,
              "hasDvdSystem" : false,
              "hasAirConditioning" : false,
              "has2SetsOfKeys" : false,
              "other" : [] } ],
          "listed" : true,
          "disclosures" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53712fa138b8d900008ef71f" ),
              "waterDamage" : false,
              "vehicleLien" : false,
              "usVehicle" : false,
              "totalLossByInsurer" : false,
              "theftOrRecovery" : false,
              "taxiOrLimo" : false,
              "structuralPartsAreDamagedOrAlteredOrRepaired" : false,
              "suspensionOrSubFrameNeedsRepair" : false,
              "repainted" : false,
              "previousDamageExceeding3k" : false,
              "powerTrainNeedsRepair" : false,
              "policeCruiser" : false,
              "outOfProvinceOrState" : false,
              "originalOwner" : false,
              "originalManufacturerVinPlate" : false,
              "originalSpecificationsChanged" : false,
              "odometerRolledBackOrReplaced" : false,
              "manufacturerWarrantyCancelled" : false,
              "manufacturerBadgesChanged" : false,
              "fuelSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "fireDamage" : false,
              "engineNeedsRepair" : false,
              "emergencyVehicle" : false,
              "electricalSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "dailyRental" : false,
              "computerNeedsRepair" : false,
              "antiLockBrakesDamagedOrInoperable" : false,
              "airbagIsMissingOrInoperable" : false,
              "airConditioningNeedsRepair" : false } ],
          "details" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53712fa138b8d900008ef71d" ),
              "year" : 2007,
              "vin" : "JN8AZ08W27W649264",
              "trim" : "SE",
              "transmission" : "Automatic",
              "price" : 132123,
              "model" : "Murano 4D Utility AWD",
              "mileageReading" : 125000,
              "make" : "Nissan",
              "interiorColor" : "Black",
              "history" : "Carproof Verified ($40.00)",
              "hasAccident" : false,
              "fuelType" : "Biodiesel",
              "exteriorColor" : "Blue",
              "driveTrain" : "FWD",
              "description" : "dsadas",
              "cylinders" : 4,
              "mileageType" : "kms" } ] }, 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "53713bfc1429925f0faf79d0" ),
          "createdAt" : Date( 1399929780000 ),
          "tags" : [ 
            "vehicle" ],
          "opts" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53713bfc1429925f0faf79ce" ),
              "hasSunroof" : false,
              "hasSnowTires" : false,
              "hasPowerWindows" : false,
              "hasNavigationSystem" : false,
              "hasManuals" : false,
              "hasMags" : false,
              "hasLeather" : false,
              "hasKeylessEntry" : false,
              "hasHeatedSeats" : false,
              "hasDvdSystem" : false,
              "hasAirConditioning" : false,
              "has2SetsOfKeys" : false,
              "other" : [] } ],
          "listed" : false,
          "disclosures" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53713bfc1429925f0faf79cf" ),
              "waterDamage" : false,
              "vehicleLien" : false,
              "usVehicle" : false,
              "totalLossByInsurer" : false,
              "theftOrRecovery" : false,
              "taxiOrLimo" : false,
              "structuralPartsAreDamagedOrAlteredOrRepaired" : false,
              "suspensionOrSubFrameNeedsRepair" : false,
              "repainted" : false,
              "previousDamageExceeding3k" : false,
              "powerTrainNeedsRepair" : false,
              "policeCruiser" : false,
              "outOfProvinceOrState" : false,
              "originalOwner" : false,
              "originalManufacturerVinPlate" : false,
              "originalSpecificationsChanged" : false,
              "odometerRolledBackOrReplaced" : false,
              "manufacturerWarrantyCancelled" : false,
              "manufacturerBadgesChanged" : false,
              "fuelSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "fireDamage" : false,
              "engineNeedsRepair" : false,
              "emergencyVehicle" : false,
              "electricalSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "dailyRental" : false,
              "computerNeedsRepair" : false,
              "antiLockBrakesDamagedOrInoperable" : false,
              "airbagIsMissingOrInoperable" : false,
              "airConditioningNeedsRepair" : false } ],
          "details" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53713bfc1429925f0faf79cd" ),
              "year" : 2007,
              "vin" : "JN8AZ08W27W649264",
              "trim" : "SE",
              "transmission" : "Manual",
              "price" : 13241234,
              "model" : "Murano 4D Utility AWD",
              "mileageReading" : 1312312,
              "make" : "Mercedes-Benz",
              "interiorColor" : "Black",
              "history" : "Carproof Claims ($25.00)",
              "hasAccident" : true,
              "fuelType" : "Diesel",
              "exteriorColor" : "Black",
              "driveTrain" : "RWD",
              "description" : "werwe",
              "cylinders" : 4,
              "mileageType" : "kms" } ] }, 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "5373c6439058859af7904a17" ),
          "createdAt" : Date( 1400095020000 ),
          "tags" : [ 
            "vehicle" ],
          "opts" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "5373c6439058859af7904a15" ),
              "hasSunroof" : false,
              "hasSnowTires" : false,
              "hasPowerWindows" : false,
              "hasNavigationSystem" : false,
              "hasManuals" : false,
              "hasMags" : false,
              "hasLeather" : false,
              "hasKeylessEntry" : false,
              "hasHeatedSeats" : false,
              "hasDvdSystem" : false,
              "hasAirConditioning" : false,
              "has2SetsOfKeys" : false,
              "other" : [] } ],
          "listed" : true,
          "disclosures" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "5373c6439058859af7904a16" ),
              "waterDamage" : false,
              "vehicleLien" : false,
              "usVehicle" : false,
              "totalLossByInsurer" : false,
              "theftOrRecovery" : false,
              "taxiOrLimo" : false,
              "structuralPartsAreDamagedOrAlteredOrRepaired" : false,
              "suspensionOrSubFrameNeedsRepair" : false,
              "repainted" : false,
              "previousDamageExceeding3k" : false,
              "powerTrainNeedsRepair" : false,
              "policeCruiser" : false,
              "outOfProvinceOrState" : false,
              "originalOwner" : false,
              "originalManufacturerVinPlate" : false,
              "originalSpecificationsChanged" : false,
              "odometerRolledBackOrReplaced" : false,
              "manufacturerWarrantyCancelled" : false,
              "manufacturerBadgesChanged" : false,
              "fuelSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "fireDamage" : false,
              "engineNeedsRepair" : false,
              "emergencyVehicle" : false,
              "electricalSystemNeedsRepair" : false,
              "dailyRental" : false,
              "computerNeedsRepair" : false,
              "antiLockBrakesDamagedOrInoperable" : false,
              "airbagIsMissingOrInoperable" : false,
              "airConditioningNeedsRepair" : false } ],
          "details" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "5373c6439058859af7904a14" ),
              "year" : 2013,
              "vin" : "12345678901234567",
              "trim" : "SE",
              "transmission" : "Automatic",
              "price" : 13564,
              "model" : "Red",
              "mileageReading" : 13453,
              "make" : "Daihatsu",
              "interiorColor" : "Black",
              "history" : "Carproof Verified ($40.00)",
              "hasAccident" : true,
              "fuelType" : "Diesel",
              "exteriorColor" : "Black",
              "driveTrain" : "FWD",
              "description" : "wrw",
              "cylinders" : 3,
              "mileageType" : "kms" } ] } ],
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "active", 
        "vehicles" ] }, 
    { "title" : "soldInventory",
      "_id" : "sold",
      "vehicles" : [],
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "sold", 
        "vehicles" ] }, 
    { "title" : "deletedInventory",
      "_id" : "deleted",
      "vehicles" : [],
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "deleted", 
        "vehicles" ] } ],
  "address" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "53712c7238b8d900008ef71b" ),
      "phoneNumber" : "4092348294",
      "country" : "Canada",
      "zip" : "301111",
      "region" : "Quebec",
      "city" : "Montreal",
      "street2" : "Apt. 101",
      "street1" : "1213 Street",
      "additionalNumbers" : [] } ],
  "__v" : 3 }
```

Comment: is the current array a result of aggregation?  if you were $push'ing opts, details, etc. into the array in vehicle, then you should probably have kept just the first element earlier in the pipeline.   Providing starting document sample may clarify this.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I made a edit with my aggregation and my original data.

Comment: ah so the original document has these subarrays, you're not assembling them yourself.  and original document had them in an array - so you unwind and you don't do any grouping yet...   I must say I'm not a fan of the original schema - having arrays embedded many levels deep only makes sense when you *always* want to return full arrays.  I think it's still possible to do this, just not pretty.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I agree, you should talk to our DB architect lol. If I was to do it myself, I would definitely not use arrays, but that's how things are right now, but I'm petitioning hard to change them (anyways I digress). It would still be neat if that specific problem could be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2.6 (which you must be since you use $redact) and if the array is always guaranteed to be empty if there are no tags or opts, you can use this technique to make sure you don't lose vehicles which have empty arrays when you `$unwind`:

In a `$project` phase add the following for all arrays you want to $unwind to keep just the first element:

```
opts:{$cond:{if:{$eq:[{$size:"$opts"},0]}, then:{$literal:[ "none" ]}, else:"$opts"}}
```

For each sub-array you can now group keeping the first one, and then repeat again for the next sub-array.

You'll need to be careful about unwinding and re-grouping for each array separately to keep from ending up with any duplication, if you are not aggregating anything else, you can do it in a single group with as many $unwinds as there are sub-arrays.